# call another activity in class that did not extend Activity class

Tags: java, android

Hi all i have a class name

```
public class WikipediaDataSource extends NetworkDataSource{.....}
```

which extend to NetworkDataSource. what im try to do is from this class i would like to call new activity...

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, Obj3DView.class);
startActivity(i);
```

i got error saying

```
the method of startActivity(intent) is undefined for the type WikipediaDataSource
```

i read a lot on this issue .. it happens because this class do not extend the activity clas.

i try to follow others solutions. but it does not work for my case.

Please help! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this line works:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, Obj3DView.class);
```

Then you already have access to a Context, just use:

```
context.startActivity(i);
```

Since [`startActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) is a method of the Context class.

---

> actually the line intent i = new Intent(context, Obj3DView.class); got error.

Often developers pass the Context in the constructor:

```
public class WikipediaDataSource extends NetworkDataSource {
    Context context;

    public WikipediaDataSource (Context ctx) {
        ...
        context = ctx;
    }
    ...
}
```

Now your code should work.

Comment: actually the line intent i = new Intent(context, Obj3DView.class);
got error. where should i declare the context ?

Comment: I did as you said. and in my main activity which i call the wikipedia class it got errors because the way i call the class is like this --->   

NetworkDataSource wikipedia = new WikipediaDataSource(this.getResources());
       sources.put("wiki",wikipedia);

later i change by adding constructor for main activity and 

Context context; 

public MainActivity(Context ctx)
{
 this.context = ctx; 
}

and edit the call code like this 

NetworkDataSource wikipedia = new WikipediaDataSource(this.getResources(),this.context);
sources.put("wiki",wikipedia);

application forced closed

Comment: what i did is 

Intent i = new Intent(context, Obj3DView.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

and on call is use 

 NetworkDataSource wikipedia = new WikipediaDataSource(this.getResources(),this.getBaseContext()); sources.put("wiki",wikipedia);

problem solved ! Thanks

     context.startActivity(i);

Answer (score 0):

In the non activity class:

```
private Activity activity;

public non_activity_class(Activity act) {

        activity=act;

}
.....`enter code here`
```

and then when you want to start a new activity

```
Intent in = new Intent("Pakege.NewActivity");
// NewActivity = what you write in your Manifest            

activity.startActivity(in);
```

In the activity class, call the constructor

```
non_activity_class(this);
```

I hope it helps.